# MOK Manager doesn't display when trying to add a new key

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, uefi

I am trying to sign the VirtualBox kernel modules using Fedora 27 with UEFI Secure Boot enabled. I have successfully signed the modules and have run

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

where MOK.der is the output file from generating the key. When I reboot, I am greeted with a message: Press any key to run MOK Management. A countdown to boot normally is shown in the bottom left of the screen. When I press a button, the countdown freezes, but nothing else happens. I have determined through pressing keys that the MOK Manager is loaded, but is not displayed on the screen.

My issue is identical to the one described on askubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950395/mok-management-will-not-load-on-boot). The person who asked the question fixed the problem by following screenshots of what they should be seeing. I have not found any screenshots of the setup process, but I do have a laptop that I have done the same process on successfully. I may be able to get through the process blind, although I have already tried once to follow the same process of adding a new key unsuccessfully.

I would like to fix the underlying issue though, since I'm apparently not the only one experiencing it. What troubleshooting steps can I take to isolate the cause of the MOK Manager not displaying?

System info:

ASRock Extreme4 X99 Motherboard, UEFI version 3.60 (most recent available)
Intel i7 5820K cpu
Sapphire Radeon R9 280X Tri-X gpu
OS: Fedora 27, kernel version 4.14.16-300.fc27.x86_64

Comment: Just in case you simply need a distribution with VirtualBox, ALT Linux builds (and maintains) many kernel modules for its packaged kernels, including kernel-modules-virtualbox-*; I've implemented UEFI support (and SB shim/signing) for it but so far interest in user signing and MOK seems next to zero...
Asking Fedora guys directly (erm, via lists/bugzilla) might result in more directly relevant advice for your question here, pjones@ was very helpful back then.

Comment: I would like to use Fedora specifically, so I'll look into contacting them via mailing lists or bugzilla. I need to be able to create and use .vmdk files for other partitions, but I guess there aren't many other people who need to create these, which would explain the lack of interest. Thanks for your help.